# array map and filter order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
[{'message':'test...'},{'message':'50 chars...'}]
```

I am using array map and filter to return all objects with a message under 50 characters.

however I came up with the following 2 solutions both producing the same result, are they both the same in terms of efficiency? or is one preferred over the other....

```
function getShortMessages(messages){
  return messages.map(function(item){
    return item.message;
  }).filter(function(message){
    return message.length < 50;
  })
}
```

in this I am using map to get the messages into an array then filtering the array of messages (strings).

```
function getShortMessages(messages) {
 return messages.filter(function(item) {
   return item.message.length < 50
 }).map(function(item) {
   return item.message
 })
}
```

in this one I am getting an array of objects with messages less then 50 characters, then I am putting the messages into an array.

what is the correct way to achieve (best practice) of the methods above?

Comment: can you user a third part library? if so you can see underscore.js http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: i like `messages.map(function(x){return x.y.length < 50 && x.y; }).filter(Boolean)` : minimal iteration, minimal hand-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `reduce()`. It is essentially what I would use if I need to filter AND map data.

Also, remove any magic numbers from inside the function. :)

```js
var shortMessages = getShortMessages(messages, 50);

function getShortMessages(messages, length) {
  return messages.reduce(function(result, item) {
    if (item.message.length < length) {
      result.push(item.message);
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

---

Personally, you can create a reducer with a predicate function which acts as a filter.

```js
// Retrieve random messages up to 70 characters long.
$.getJSON('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bLTLHYsXDm?indent=2',
  function(messages) {
    $.each(getShortMessages(messages, 70), function(index, message) {
      $('<p>').text(message).appendTo('body');
    });
  });

// Define message length predicate and map callback.
function getShortMessages(messages, limit) {
  return mapReducer(messages, function() {
    return this.message.length < limit;
  }, function() {
    return this.message;
  });
}

// Combine map and filter, using a reduce function.
function mapReducer(list, filterFn, mapperFn) {
  return list.reduce(function(result, item, index, arr) {
    if (filterFn.call(item, item, index, arr)) {
      result.push(mapperFn.call(item, item, index, arr));
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: one downside of a reduce is that it's less composable (can't independently adjust criterion and pluck) and doesn't use a pure function callback...

Answer (score 0):

If you `filter` first, you will end up `map`ing over an array that is at most the length of the original array. So if you're looking for micro optimizations, you should `filter` first, then `map`.

In practice, however, either is fine (this would only become an issue if your original list is VERY long and perhaps the `map` transformation is VERY expensive. In this case, it might be wise to follow [@MrPolywhirl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762224/mr-polywhirl)'s answer and use a different approach (ie use `reduce`).